# Retrieve data from two tables in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created 2 tables and 2 model classes, one for `Lookups` and another one for `Lookup_Types`.

All CRUD operations and indexes for `Lookup_Types` are OK, but then I need to return `Lookup_name` not `Lookup_type_id`.

My models :

```
 public class Lookup_Type
 {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3,
         ErrorMessage = "Name Should be minimum 3 characters and a maximum of 50 characters")]
        public string Lookup_name { get; set; }
 }

public class Lookup
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3,
        ErrorMessage = "Name Should be minimum 3 characters and a maximum of 50 characters")]
    public string Lookup_name { get; set; }

    public int Lookup_type_id { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
   return Json(new { data = await _db.Lookups.ToListAsync() });
}
```

In `GetAll()`, I need to return `Lookup_name` in `Lookup_Type` model, not `Lookup_type_id`

Comment: Assuming that _db.Lookups.ToListAsync() returns a list of Lookup instances, do you want to map that list to a list of strings with the value of Lookup_name? Is Lookup_name a column with a valid value that is being mapped from the underlying table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
    var data =  from l in _context.Lookup
                join t in _context.Lookup_Type
                on l.Lookup_type_id equals t.Id

                select new
                {
                    l.Id,
                    l.Lookup_name,
                    Lookup_Type_name = t.Lookup_name
                };
    return Json(new { data = await data.ToListAsync() });         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join two table, but in `Lookup_Type` table, name should change to `Lookup_Type_name`

```
 data = await from x in _db.Lookups
                             join y in db.Lookup_Type
                             on x.Lookup_type_id equals y.Id

                             select new
                             {
                                 Id = x.Id,
                                 Lookup_name = x.Lookup_name ,
                                 Lookup_Type_name = y.Lookup_Type_name

                             }
```